# Online repository/encyclopedia of latex snippet for mathematical equations

Tags: math-software

So that I don't have to retype them every single time.
e.g. I'll only need to type "Fourier transform" to get the template.

Sure, I could look up the Latex code from the page source in Wikipedia, but it would be nicer if I could search the code directly.

Comment: This is not what you are looking for, but maybe it's notable that on the arxiv you can also access the latex source code that was submitted.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use $\backslash$newcommand to create your own package with commands you often use. Another nice website to find symbols, whose name you always forget, is http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: sorry for not being specific. What I meant is formula template, like $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$. sorry for being lazy, but your link is pretty cool too.

Comment: If I couldn't find any repository like I mentioned before, then I'll go create one. maybe it'll be more useful in science/engineering, since they have more named' equations.

Comment: The first idea I mentioned was defining something like \newcommand{euler}{$e^{i\pi}+1=0$}. Then you can use the command \euler to print this formula. You can create your own collection of handy commands this way.